# Problem returning an input value within a while loop in Python

Tags: python, class, while-loop, return-value

I have a question with my code in Python. I want to return a value for the Input.input_pos() function within this class.
if I type one of the conditional values when I am asked to input while running the program, it returns correctly, but if I input something else and the else condition or the exception occurs, the function loops (which I meant to do that), but when I type again one of the conditional values (either 6, 7, 8, 9 or 10), it doesn't return any value anymore. Why is that?

I am sure it doesn't return a value because I use that value for another function and also when I print it, it shows None in the console.

I tried using the continue keyword after calling again the function within the class. That kinda fixes the problem, but makes the function to loop itself as many time as I input something out of the conditional values.

Can someone tell how can I make this not to occur and instead return the value even when it has looped?

```
class Input():
    def input_pos():
        while True:
            try:
                postura = int(input("Postura "))
                if postura == 6:
                    return 6
                elif postura == 7:
                    return 7
                elif postura == 8:
                    return 8
                elif postura == 9:
                    return 9
                elif postura == 10:
                    return 10
                else:
                    print("debes escribir un número del 6 al 10")
                    Input.input_pos()

            except ValueError:
                print("Error, debes elegir un número del 6 al 10")
                Input.input_pos()
            except Exception:
                print("Error, debes elegir un número del 6 al 10")
                Input.input_pos()
            break
```

Comment: Recursive functions are probably not ideal for this, but if you are going to use them you need to return the value from the recursive calls in all the places you call it: `return Input.input_pos()`

Comment: You are using a loop **and** a recursive call. Drop one of them, preferably the recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using while to reassign the value until the input is successful and then the loop will jump out and return

```
class Input:
    def input_pos(self):

        postura = input("Postura: ")

        while postura not in ["6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]:
            postura = input("debes escribir un número del 6 al 10: ")
        return int(postura)


print(Input().input_pos())
```

Output:

```
Postura: 1
debes escribir un número del 6 al 10: 4
debes escribir un número del 6 al 10: 67
debes escribir un número del 6 al 10: 6
6
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Man! you really nailed it and it works properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Input():
    def input_pos(self):
        while True:
            try:
                postura = int(input("Postura "))
                if 6 <= postura <= 10:
                    return postura
                else:
                    print("debes escribir un número del 6 al 10")
                    return self.input_pos()
            except Exception:
                print("Error, debes elegir un número del 6 al 10")
                return self.input_pos()
            break
print(Input.input_pos())
```

Output:

```
Postura as
Error, debes elegir un número del 6 al 10
Postura 2
debes escribir un número del 6 al 10
Postura 11
debes escribir un número del 6 al 10
Postura 8
8
```